# Jquery deffered object resolve after ajax requests done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code which is ran after form submit. it is AJAX requests based. 
Problem I have is in `FormSubmit` function at `Validation.done(function(){` i get error message saying **Uncaught TypeError: Validation.done is not a function**. But if you look `FormValidate` function it returns `deferredObject.promise` 
which is resolved or rejected in ajax done or fail.

So where is the problem??

When user submits form we run action:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#NewOrder").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        FormSubmit("NewOrder");
        return false;
    });
});

function FormSubmit(FormId)
{
    var Validation = FormValidate(FormId);
    Validation.done(function(){
       //Do stuff if validation succeeded
    });
}
```

`FormValidate` function:

```
function FormValidate(FormId)
{
    var deferredObject = $.Deferred();

    var url = "../../ajax/FormValidate";
    var data = {};

    var promise = AjaxRequest(url, data);

    promise.done(function(response) {
        var resultArray = JSON.parse(response);
        var FormEntity = $('#'+FormId).attr('entity');

        if($.isEmptyObject(resultArray)){
            deferredObject.resolve();
        }
        else{
            $.each(resultArray, function( key, value ) {                
                $( "div#"+key+"_validation" ).text(value);              
            });         
            deferredObject.reject();
        }
    });

    promise.fail(function(response) {
        deferredObject.reject();
        console.log(response);      
    });

    return deferredObject.promise;
}
```

`AjaxRequest` function:

```
function AjaxRequest(url, data)
{
    var deferredObject = $.Deferred();

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
    });

    request.done(function (response){
        deferredObject.resolve(response);
    });

    request.fail(function (response){
        deferredObject.reject(response);
    });

    return deferredObject.promise();
}
```

Comment: `return deferredObject.promise;` should be `return deferredObject.promise();`

Comment: Don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi where and how would you improve this code? Because I really don't understand as this is a new thing for me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deferredObject.promise` is a function. You need to call it to obtain the promise.

```
return deferredObject.promise();
```

Comment: Seems you already knew that since you are calling it in your other function. Typo?

Answer (score 0):

You are heavily using the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). Instead of explicitly constructing a deferred and using `.done` and `.fail` handlers on the given promise to resolve/reject, just use the `.then` method:

```
function FormValidate(FormId) {
    var url = "../../ajax/FormValidate";
    var data = {};

    return AjaxRequest(url, data).then(function(response) {
        var resultArray = JSON.parse(response);
        var FormEntity = $('#'+FormId).attr('entity');

        if ($.isEmptyObject(resultArray)) return; // resolve with undefined
        $.each(resultArray, function(key, value) {
            $("div#"+key+"_validation").text(value);
        });
        return $.Deferred().reject(resultArray); // if not empty
    }, console.log.bind(console));
}

function AjaxRequest(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
    });
}
```

Then your typo with those `.promise()` calls wouldn't have happened either :-)